# Where is the current position of a file during a read/write operation is kept?

Tags: read-write, inode

When a file is being read/written, where is the current position within the file is  kept? Is it in the inode or a is it a processor variable?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on your perspective. Operating systems abstract these details away from the application developer, but you might be (trying to learn about) developing an operating system. Could you tell us about your goal?

Comment: Yes, I'm learning about file systems for an OS exam

Comment: A question about how to program something would be more appropriate. Is there a question about the programming of file access that you could ask?